# jconsole operation ordering

Tags: java, jconsole, mbeans

I'd like to find a way to order the operations listed for an MBean in jconsole so my most commonly used methods appear at the top of the list. I've tried to reverse engineer how jconsole is doing this without success. Thanks in advance.

jdk=1.6.0_24

Comment: Yes! I'd like to know this also. The order of operations is somewhat random (usually, not not always, in the order of declaration). Some consistency would be nice here... so many times I almost click on the wrong operation when testing my service. Also affects `1.7.0_25`...